# set Android ZoomButtonsController alignment?

Tags: android, android-layout, zooming

Im implementing a ZoomButtonsController in my custom View and have been trying to figure out how to align it to the bottom right hand corner of the screen (it aligns to the bottom middle by default) but havent had any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZoomButtonsController can be defined in XML files and can be positioned accordingly , for eg.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<ZoomControls android:id="@+id/zoomControls1" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</ZoomControls>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This layout will make your zoomcontrols in top-right of the screen as defined by the attributes ,

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

so basically you can align your views by nesting them in a Layout (like RelativeLayout , LinearLayout etc.)

Comment: how could i define it in the code? I use        ZoomButtonsController controller = (ZoomButtonsController) findViewById(R.id.zoomControls);
but im getting a cast error in eclipse

Comment: you should use ZoomButtons controller = (ZoomButtons)findViewById(R.id.zoomControls)

Comment: after doing that im unable to use my setOnZoomListener method to call it

Comment: you can use setOnZoomInClickListener , and setOnZoomOutClickListener