# Center Zoom Buttons in WebView?

Tags: android, webview, zooming

By default the zoom buttons in `WebView` are aligned to the right, is it possible to make them align center? Thanks in advance for your answers! :)

Comment: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294598/set-android-zoombuttonscontroller-alignment) may be this could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think it is possible using the published APIs