# How do I position ZoomButtonsController in custom ImageView?

Tags: android, layout, imageview

Layouting in Android is getting me rather perplexed.
I'm slowly implementing a custom ImageView where I'd like to make use of the ZoomButtonsController.
However, I would like to decide where the zoom buttons go in the layout and I can't figure out how to move them from the default bottom center position.

I have been experimenting with layouting simple views such as buttons in the main activity and this seems to be working as I would guess and expect.
In the case of the ZoomButtonsController I would however like to reposition them. I'm using a RelativeLayout as the mail layout and add the ZoomButtonsController within the custom ImageView.

The Activity code

```
public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        CustomImageView imageView = new CustomImageView(this);
        relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
}
```

The CustomImageView code

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
    private ZoomButtonsController mZoomButtons;

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        mZoomButtons = new ZoomButtonsController(this);
        mZoomButtons.getZoomControls();
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        Log.d("TAG", "touch");
        mZoomButtons.setVisible(true);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've tested with WRAP_CONTENT in the parameters, but this only makes the zoom buttons disappear.

Comment: according to [set Android ZoomButtonsController alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294598/set-android-zoombuttonscontroller-alignment) you can define the zoombuttons in the layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a matter of fact, I couldn't position the ZoomButtonsController in any way and in the end had to accept the default placement.