# How can i make BuiltInZoom zoomin/out button in webview to align top?

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to align the BuiltInZoom button to align to left or at the top in a webview,
by default it appears at the bottom of webview when we scroll the webview .

I have used following code to enable it.

```
web.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
web.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

[image]

Does any one know the solution for it.?
ThankQ.

Answer (score 0):

use this in xml to set alignment of controls

```
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

or visit this:
[set Android ZoomButtonsController alignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294598/set-android-zoombuttonscontroller-alignment)

Comment: i'm using default ZoomControls so , there is no code for ZoomControls in my layout.

Comment: then i don't think it is possible using published api.